# Background Image not displaying in node-js server using express and Jade

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I'm creating a minor project using nodejs-express-jade.

My index.jade file reads:

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        #login-container
        form( method="post")#login-form.well.span4
            h1 Welcome
            p.subheading Please Login To Your Account
            label Username 
            input(type="text", name="user", id='user-tf').span4.required
            label Password
            input(type="password", name="pass", id='pass-tf').span4.required
            button(type="submit")#btn-login.btn.btn-primary
                i.icon-lock.icon-white
                | Sign in
            div.clear-fix
```

And my stylesheet style.css has:

```
body {
  padding: 300px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color:black; 
  background-image: url("C:/Users/nrao/Desktop/nodejs/npm-1.4.6/KrishiMoney/image.jpg");
}

a {
  color: #8F2929;
}
```

When I make changes to the font and padding fields it gets reflected in the page but the background-image fields is not getting reflected. What could the reason for this be?

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon on your `bg-color` line.

Comment: corrected it,  but it still wont work @TylerH

Comment: The background color shows up but the image does'nt show up. @TylerH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background image is absolute path for your machine. You should use relative path based on the server.

Comment: How do you make the path relative to the server directory? Thanks.

Comment: How are you serving your CSS from? I mean which web server are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to reply back. I figured it out on my own. I was using nodejs-express with jade. If you are curious, the CSS was here: https://github.com/neilbalch/RPi-Computer-Power/blob/master/RPi-Server/public/stylesheets/style.css